# html text field bulk data is not showing in struts2 action class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2, textbox

I have a data of 500 lines in html i want to get it in my action class for this I have html form as follows :

```
<form action="test" method="post" name="divContent" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <textarea rows="30" cols="55" name="tableData" id="dataTable"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="data" onclick="getData();" />       
</form>


Interceptor



<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="cachingHeadersInterceptor" class="org.nic.eoffice.mis.security.utils.CachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultSecurityStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="cachingHeadersInterceptor"/>
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
```

and my action method is

```
public String generateReport() {
        Map qparam = getReportQueryParams();

        /*
         * Blow Lines are used in case of Whole List
         */
        if (null == getTemplate() && null != getReportModel().getTemplate()) {
            setTemplate(getReportModel().getTemplate());
        }
        try {
            ListConfig listConfig = (ListConfig) Util.getSpringBean("listConfig");
            ListDef listDef = null;
            if (null != getTemplate() && getTemplate().toString().contains("hierarchy_wise")) {
                listDef = listConfig.getListDef("diaryregisterhierarchywise/list");
            } else if (null != getTemplate() && getTemplate().toString().contains("department_wise")) {
                listDef = listConfig.getListDef("diaryregister/list");
            }
            fields = listDef.getFields();
            dataList = listConfig.getListData(qparam, listDef.getQueryDef(), 0, -1, "", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputCriteria = new Util().prepareListHeader(getReportModel());
        inputCriteria.add(new SelectOption("template", template));

        if (null != outputColumnsList && outputColumnsList.size() > 0)
            inputCriteria.add(new SelectOption("outputColumnList",
                    outputColumnsList));
        else if (null != getReportModel().getOutputColumnsList() && getReportModel().getOutputColumnsList().size() > 0) {
            /*
             * This is used in case of Whole List
             */
            outputColumnsList.addAll(getReportModel().getOutputColumnsList());
            inputCriteria.add(new SelectOption("outputColumnList",  getReportModel().getOutputColumnsList()));
        }

        //This is used for action like Html view or PDF view.
        if(null == dataList || dataList.size() <= 0 ){
            addFieldError("DataList", "No Data Found");
            return SUCCESS;
        }       

        if (getReportType().equalsIgnoreCase("Generate Report")) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else if (getReportType().equalsIgnoreCase("Print Report")) {
            return "printReport";
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

in This all data members is define and they have the getter setter also.

In textarea I want to submit a data of 500 Lines the size of text is near 2 Mb it is not displaying in my action class in `tableData` field i got null again and again.

If anybody have the solution of that please share us.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your action and your interceptor stack

Comment: Do you want to test a browser for buffer overflow error?

Comment: @Roman no i want to HTML page content in my action for print or make pdf...

Comment: @shivam: What happens if you submit less data from that form (e.g. `test string`)?

Comment: @Aleksandr M for less data it is working fine and generate PDF successfully.

Comment: Then it could be the problem with you app server, which doesn't allow so much data in the request. You need to configure your server.

Comment: If possible then can u tell me about the configuration what i have to do ?

Comment: It depends on the server you are using.